# How to measure testability of Java classes?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, testability

I want to implement JUnit tests in order to do some refactoring. First I'd like to check how good the class is, whether it's implemented for testability. Is there any metric and tools I could use to measure how testable a Java class is?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're looking for the [Testability Explorer](https://code.google.com/p/testability-explorer/). Latest code seems to be on [github](https://github.com/mhevery/testability-explorer).